# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Order::meta() in file

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I  Can Access this result as `return $value` and can access `user_id` as `$retun $value->user_id`

```
{
    "id": 250,
    "user_id": 53,
    "meta": {
        "sub_total": 2050,
        "charge": 0,
  
    }
}
```

**How Can I access the `sub_total` like the same way?**
I have Tried `$value->meta('sub_total')`
got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because meta not method to call . meta is attribute in your object , so you can try to access it like this :- `$value->meta->sub_total` , or you can convert $value to array and access its indexs like this:  `$value['meta']['sub_total'];` , and you can avoiding errors by using optional method like this :- optional`($value['meta'])['sub_total']` or optional`($value->meta)->sub_total`